# Can anyone tell me where to donate a lot of Hero Factory parts and pieces?

Tags: bionicle

Wondering where to donate gently used Hero Factory parts and pieces. Surely there are people who might want them. Not sure if Goodwill will take them. I have already tried eBay. Any other ideas? I'd hate to put them in the trash. I'm in the metro Atlanta, GA area.  Thanks!

Comment: Please update question to include your country, at least.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd try one of the following:

1. If you wish to get some money for them, post them as an auction on eBay without a minimal (reserve) price. This way somebody will surely bid at least some amount, and the lot will be off your hands and on it's way to someone who actually wants it at least a bit.
2. Posting on local marketplace boards (like Craigslist, Facebook Marketplace, etc.) could attract some interested recipients as well, either for money or for free.
3. If you don't want to get any compensation for it, you could try local kindergartens - I suppose they would welcome additional toys for the kids there.
4. If all else fails, you could just pack them up in a bag, attach a note abut what it is and what are your intentions, then leave the bag in a playground for someone to find. This is the most risky option, as parents in your area might be rightfully hesitant to let their kids pick up anything remotely suspicious, but it surely beats throwing the lot in the trash.

Comment: Thanks for much for your suggestions,  I was hoping to get about $20 for them, but after several days on fb marketplace and ebay with no takers, I'm ready to give them away for free to someone who wants them

Comment: Several days is not a lot of time. On eBay the usual auction times range from one to two weeks, I'd suggest trying a longer time to increase the number of visitors and with it the chances.

Comment: I would also add that you might find a fan of Hero Factory in your local LEGO User Group (LUG).

Comment: You rarely get bids on Ebay until near the end of the auction. Why would somebody bid early $1 for an item with no bids that they think is worth $100, when their bid will alerts other buyers and someone else will bid $2? Of course the person who wants to bid $2 will also not bid till the last minute, otherwise the first bidder would probably bid $3. The way to get a real bargain on Ebay is to make "sniping bid" a few seconds before the auction ends, not to show your interest early.

Comment: Extending the default auction length on Ebay is fairly pointless, unless you are selling something which is obviously rare and desirable, and you want to start a bidding war between several potential buyers. For a random collection of Lego parts, that is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a local elementary school? In the UK, Lego is very popular in therapy sessions, and for social support groups.

Answer (score 1):

For donating LEGO, I would look at local libraries.  Many public libraries in my region of the US have "LEGO clubs" and are always looking for spare brick.  I also agree with an earlier answer that you might want to look for any adult LEGO clubs in your area.  Even if the adults fans are not interested in what you have they often have connections to people who want spare LEGO.

Another source for donations could be FIRST LEGO LEAGUE robotic teams in your area.  These teams are often in need of spare parts and even Hero Factory pieces can be used for decorating the robots.

Whatever you do, don't put them in the trash.  ABS is a very recyclable material, but furthermore LEGO is in high demand.  It would be multiple levels of shame to put it in a landfill.  My guess is that Goodwill wil take them, as I often bring the clone bricks to thrift shops when I separate them from second hand LEGO piles that I grab at yard sales or Facebook marketplace.